# Xamarin.Forms Cant see Print Option in UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

why I cant see the Print option in menu what I miss

```
private void OpenExtrnal()
        {


            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {

                UIView parentView = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View;
                CGRect buttonFrame = new CGRect( 0 , -260 , 320 , 320);
                var PreviewController = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(new NSUrl(localDocUrl, true));
                PreviewController.Delegate = new UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateClass(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController);
                if(passedImage != null && Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet){
                    buttonFrame = FormsViewToNativeiOS.ConvertFormsToNative(passedImage).Frame;
                }

                PreviewController.PresentOpenInMenu(buttonFrame , parentView ,  true);
            });
        }
```

Delegate Class

```
public class UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateClass : UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
    {
        UIViewController viewC;

        public UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateClass(UIViewController controller)
        {
            viewC = controller;
        }

        public override UIViewController ViewControllerForPreview(UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
        {
            return viewC;
        }

        public override UIView ViewForPreview(UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
        {
            return viewC.View;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `PreviewController.PresentOptionsMenu` instead of `PreviewController.PresentOpenInMenu` to display the options such as the "Print".

The difference between the `PresentOpenInMenu` and `PresentOptionsMenu` is here:

> - To prompt the user with a set of options, including an option to open the file in another app, call the `presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` or `presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:` method.
> - To prompt the user only to open the file in another app, call the `presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` or `presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:` method.

Refer to the Apple Documentation: [Presenting a Document Interaction Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW16).

Comment: Hi @Mina, did my answer help you?

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please accept it. It's important to me. Thanks:)